# Trouble with Display images

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a trouble with display images when using Play + java

First, I upload it, when i click upload. the image will show in browser.

The trouble appeared in here.

If i follow the code :

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("upload/abc.png")" width="304" height="228">
```

this worked fine. But if i fix it like :

```
@(filename:String)
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("upload/@filename")" width="304" height="228">
//Ofcourse filename=="abc.png"
```

The images not shown.

Is `@filename` not working or i was wrong in somewhere ? gramma ? logic ?

And ideal with my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's literally looking for a file named `upload/@filename`. The first `@` already started an expression, so after that you need to use the variable name without `@` and just append it to the string.

```
@(filename:String)
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("upload/" + filename)" width="304" height="228">
```